# Need help to understand code

Tags: java

I've come across some code and am having trouble understanding it. It has two classes. 
Here's the first class. I haven't pasted the whole code since it is the components that I'm interested in not the code.

```
public class PizzaMain
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    PizzaT array[] = new PizzaT[2];             //Would this be an instance?
    PizzaT pizzaList = new PizzaT(" ", "", -1); //Would this be an instance?

    Scanner sNew = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = -1;

    int result = pizzaList.Menu();
```

Class two

```
public class PizzaT
{
String name, delivery;
int miles;

PizzaT(String n, String d, int m)      //This must be the constructor
{
    name =n;
    delivery =d;
    miles =m;
}

PizzaT sort(PizzaT pizzaList[], int l, String n)    //What is the pizzaList here
//Is it an instance too?
{
 ...............
}
```

Comment: Better to learn basics of java

Comment: @mahesh Yes, that is what I am doing. Looking at code and trying to understand it first.

Comment: Why all the down votes? Never mind me but why Leo? He was just trying to help. Sorry @Leo

Comment: PizzaT array[] = new PizzaT[2]; is better if you write it like PizzaT[] array = new PizzaT[2]; its more clearer that way that it is an array of pizzat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PizzaT array[] = new PizzaT[2];             //Would this be an instance?
```

No, this is an array of PizzaT

```
PizzaT pizzaList = new PizzaT(" ", "", -1); //Would this be an instance?
```

Yes, this is a PizzaT instance

```
PizzaT(String n, String d, int m)      //This must be the constructor
```

Yes. A constructor looks like a method but without any return type

```
PizzaT sort(PizzaT pizzaList[], int l, String n)    //What is the pizzaList here
//Is it an instance too?
```

No. pizzaList here is an Array (see the brackets). This array may contain PizzaT instances or not. (in a sense that may just be empty)

Comment: Ofcourse, with the brackets I should have figured it was an array *face palm*

Answer (score 0):

case 1 : Here you creating object of `Arrays` class which can hold of type `PizzaT`,
         You can learn easily [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm) and [here](http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/arrays.cfm)

case 2: Here you are creating a Instance of type `PizzaT` Because you are calling  constructor of class `PizzaT`,
        Learn how to create objects [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm)

case 3:  You can understand by case 2,
         Understand constructors [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html)

Case 4: Here `PizzaT pizzaList[]`, Method argument which expects array of PizzaT's,You just learn Array in java from above link from `case1` you will get clear idea.

```
pizzaList
```

Is reference variable, You should not ask `Is it an instance?` ,its meaning less to ask that question,better ask "What is the type of reference variable"

Where ever you use `new` keyword for sure you are creating a `instance`, question is, Of what type?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the array part. It is not an instance of the class you are making an array of objects of the class specified.

Next,  yes you are trying to make an  instance of `PizzaT` class.

Next, that is certainly the constructor same name as of class specified and  no explicit return type.

Lastly, it is not an instance but a reference variable of `PizzaT` class array.